# passing an parameter to an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I created an array of objects like this:

```
Handler handlers[] = new Handler[4];
```

Each handler object takes in a socket object as parameter. How do I pass through the socket for the handlers? I guess more generally how do I pass through arguments in an array of objects?

I've tried this:

`handlers[1](someSocket);`

and it (obviously?) didn't work.

Comment: You've created an array. You haven't created **any** `Handler` objects.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis okay, wow I think I've figured it out. Would I do this for all of the members of the array: `handlers[0] = new Handler(listener.accept());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each element in the array. Create a new handler, pass it a socket, and store it in the array like this:

```
Handler handlers[] = new Handler[4];
for(int index=0;index<4;index++){
    handlers[index]= new Handler(socket);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
Handler handlers[] = new Handler[4];
```

Allocates room for 4 `Handler` instances, it doesn't allocate any actual `Handler`(s). You could do something like,

```
Handler[] handlers = new Handler[4];
for (int i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
  handlers[i] = new Handler();
}
```

or even

```
Handler[] handlers = new Handler[] {
  new Handler(), new Handler(), new Handler(), new Handler()
};
```